# How should I structure a centralized configuration file for environment variables in node?

Tags: node.js, configuration, environment-variables

I have a node application that is deployed to a variety of different networks, so the env variables change across them all. Currently, `process.env` is being used everywhere and it's growing, so it becomes hard to manage, track, configure, etc.

What is the best way to organize and structure this type of issue? I was thinking about just writing a class with a function and a map that returns what I ask for and call it from the respective files, is this a good, simple approach?

Answer (score 0):

I use the [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) package for this purpose.  It lets me load various environment variables as config parameters.

For example, I can do

```
  const config = require( 'config' )
  const myAppConfig = config.get( 'MyApp' )
  const privateKey = myAppConfig.privateKey
  const publicKey = myAppConfig.publicKey
```

This looks in the /config directory for various config files. You can read about them; they have an elaborate setup suitable for all kinds of deployment environments.

The package also looks in that directory for the file named `custom-environment-variables.json`. It specifies how to map environment variables to config parameters.

Here's an example of that file that loads the environment variables `MY_PRIVATE_KEY` and `MY_PUBLIC_KEY`.

```
{
  "MyApp" : {
    "privateKey": "MY_PRIVATE_KEY",
    "publicKey": "MY_PUBLIC_KEY"
  }
}
```

This approach to configuration is very robust and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can have **.env** file in your project.
For example

```
PORT=5000
USER_TOKEN_SECRET='yourSecret'
MONGODB_URI='mongodb://localhost/test'
```

after it just use in your config file

```
require('dotenv').config();
import env from 'env-var';

export const mongoUrl = env.get('MONGODB_URI').asString();
export const apiUrl = env.get('API_URL').asString();
```